# Spring build CSV String and download a file with it

Tags: java, spring

What I want is when I access `/getcsv` to download an `csv file`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getcsv", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void getCSV(HttpServletResponse response){

    String csv = "a,b";

    response.setContentType("text/csv");

    //what to do now?

}
```

I don't know how to provoke download of an `csv file` which contain my String.

Comment: Use CSVPrinter for example.

Comment: Is using predefined libraries of any kind an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write data in outputStream of response.

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/getcsv", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void getCSV(HttpServletResponse response){

        String csv = "a,b";
        response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "fileName.csv");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers","Authorization, Content-Disposition");
        try (PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(response.getOutputStream())) {
            pw.write(csv);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code.

```
@PostMapping(value = "/getcsv", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
  public ResponseEntity<?> downloadFile(@RequestParam("fileName") String fileName) {
    String dirPath = "E:/some-directory-path/";
    byte[] fileBytes = null;
    try {
      fileBytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(dirPath + fileName));
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return ResponseEntity.ok()
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
        .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"")
        .body(fileBytes);
  }
```

You have to set as Application Octet Stream to download any file.